# What app can I use to change sound levels in GNOME 3 (fallback)?

Tags: audio, gnome3

With GNOME 2, I use my the volume control applet to change loudness levels. It doesn't load on GNOME 3 (fallback) applet, so I wonder what other UI can I use for this, preferably a GNOME one.

Comment: why it doesn't load?

Comment: no idea; probably broken

Comment: anything wrong with alsa-mixer?

Comment: @Behrooz: haven't tried it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Add `gnome-volume-control-applet` to the startup applications.